# Что делает данная строка кода?

Tags: c#

Что делает выделенная строка?

```
public class Presenter
{
    private readonly IView _view;
    private readonly IService _service;

    public Presenter(IView view, IService service)
    {
        _view = view;
        _service = service;

        _view.UserIdChanged += () => UpdateUserInfo();  // <<<<<<
    }

    private void UpdateUserInfo()
    {
        var user = _service.GetUser(_view.UserId);
        _view.Username = user.Username;
        _view.Age = user.Age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подчеркнутая строка подписывает обработчик `UpdateUserInfo` на событие `_view.UserIdChanged`.
Таким образом, при наступлении события `_view.UserIdChanged`, будет вызван метод `UpdateUserInfo`.

Comment: Можно ли переписать данную строку без лямбд? Если да, то как?

Comment: @J.John я уверен, что да. Попробуйте: `_view.UserIdChanged += UpdateUserInfo;`.

Comment: Судя по формату лямбды, да, можно подписаться самим методом, а лямбду туда видимо от великого ума запихнули, либо забыли убрать той же причине.